# how do I add data manipulation to the $resource object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

As per the android-phone tutorial, I'm using the $resource object to add a convenient way to grab data and have it lazily loaded into a scoped variable. My issue is that I want to have another query that manipulates the data grabbed by $resource and returns that. I don't see any way to do it with resource.

Does anyone know how I could manipulate the data that will be returned by $resource? Or can someone recommend me another lazy loaded way to do this. The function doesn't need to be as custom tailored as $resource appears to be to REST.

(Note: Angular seems way more complicated than it should be, but I'm thinking that is because of a lack of truly good tutorials. [also I can't stand video tutorials, because they are boring and time consuming and not as conveniently interactive as text tutorials])

Comment: regarding tutorials: http://www.yearofmoo.com/tags/AngularJS.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resource` uses [promises](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) and/or callbacks, like [`$http`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http).

Example:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
var user = User.get({userId:123}, function() {
    // do something with user
    user.abc = true;
    user.$save();
});
```

or:

```
var User = $resource('/user/:userId', {userId:'@id'});
User.get({userId:123}, function(user) {
    // do something with user
    user.abc = true;
    user.$save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for citing the documentation, but I still don't understand how I would use it in my situation.

Say the default is an array of objects with a name property and other properties. I want my factory to return this lazily loaded data with a member (that is also lazily loaded) that has the complete data, and another (lazily loaded) that is simply an array of the names that each object has. So allData would eventually contain [{name: 'first', other: 22}, {...}] and justNames would eventually contain ['first', ...]

Comment: If you have a more precise situation, then please phrase a more precise question with code example.

Comment: Ok, I understand. This was a stupid question. I'm prototyping an idea and the whole situation is ridiculous and would never come up in a finished product, so I'm just prototyping wrong.

I'm using a rest service tool to do non-restful things, which defeats the purpose of such a specific tool.

Thanks for your help. You answered the specific question. Cheers.